# Jquery click does not work in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, spring-mvc, browser

I have a template (a jsp file in Spring MVC framework) with the "fulfill" button (when a user clicks on it, it will redirect to another page).

I have verified that my code works on my local desktop (using both Chrome and Firefox) that when I clicked on the "fulfill" button, it successfully redirected to another page.

But when I tested it in the chrome on an Android phone and clicked on the button, nothing happened.

```
My JavaScript:

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fulfillButton').click(function() {
      location.href = "/tt/fulfill/order/${orderID}";

    });
});
```

My html:

```
<button id="fulfillButton" type="button" class="action-button shadow animate green">
       FulFill
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If solution given by Adi not work, try to register event after some time as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('#fulfillButton').click(function() {
      location.href = "/tt/fulfill/order/${orderID}";
     });
   },200);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid this way of button `click` call.

You should try given code or you can call a function, on `click event` which will also help you out.

```
    <html>   
    <button onclick="submitQuery()"></button>
    </html>  
      <script>
    function submitQuery(){
    //Do whatever You wish
    }
</script>
<script>
//Another way
    $('#fulfillButton').on('click',function(){
             //Place code here
        });
        </script>
```

Noting though that .on() supports several other parameter combinations that .click() doesn't, allowing it to handle event delegation (superceding .delegate() and .live()).

Comment: are there any reasons that on('click', function() will work in the Android browser? May you provide an example for "you can cal on a function onclick method which will also help you out"

Comment: Now Please check the Above difference. and try to avoid using jquery methods use pure javascript which will even work in webview..

Answer (score 1):

You can try touch events. it should work on both android and iPhones

ex: replace **click** with **touchstart click**

```
$('#whatever').on('touchstart click', function(){ /* do something... */ });
```

Comment: do i need to add any imports?

Comment: Nothing needed. jQuery import is enough.